# How to customize msedge's command line options with playwright-python?

Tags: automation, playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

When I launch msedge manually, in `edge://version` I can find the command line options are

```bash
--no-startup-window /prefetch:5 --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
```

If I start the same browser with `playwright`, then the options become

```bash
--disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-back-forward-cache --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-component-update --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync,Translate --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-pipe --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end about:blank
```

Is there any way I can get rid of those preset options? I have already try the `args` options and it just appends new options to the list.